# VSC: Save to multiple folders at once

Tags: git, xampp, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code and I was wondering if it is possible to save to multiple folders at once.

I'm using Git to source control and XAMPP to check if everything is working as intended, but these are two different folders so it's a bit of a pain to have to copy everything over to check if everything is working.

I've tried to change the XAMPP settings to change the folder from `C:\xampp\htdocs` to my Git folder, but that doesn't show any files.

Comment: Optimize your workflow. There is not reason for them to be different folders.

Comment: Yeah, I probably have to copy everything over and delete my old git folder and change it to the xampp one. Hopefully it won't be to much of a hassle to set it all up again.
Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Clone the repository? Just move the folder? Setup your XAMPP properly? There are so many options...